# ./flash-all.sh not working for bricked pixel 3a (fastboot devices detected)

Tags: fastboot

I had installed Ubuntu touch on my Pixel 3a, but during an OTA update the phone got soft bricked.

I am able to detect the phone through fastboot devices (using Ubuntu computer to access phone).

Tried installing sargo stock image 3 times, but without success. Still get the "no valid slot to boot" error.

Sharing the ./flash-all.sh run code below. Look forward to guidance. Thanks !

---

```
Sending 'bootloader_b' (8369 KB)                   OKAY [  0.460s]
Writing 'bootloader_b'                             (bootloader) Flashing Pack version b4s4-0.3-6622442
(bootloader) Flashing partition table for Lun = 0
(bootloader) Flashing partition xbl_b
(bootloader) Flashing partition xbl_config_b
(bootloader) Flashing partition tz_b
(bootloader) Flashing partition aop_b
(bootloader) Flashing partition hyp_b
(bootloader) Flashing partition keymaster_b
(bootloader) Flashing partition cmnlib_b
(bootloader) Flashing partition cmnlib64_b
(bootloader) Flashing partition abl_b
(bootloader) Flashing partition devcfg_b
(bootloader) Flashing partition qupfw_b
(bootloader) Flashing partition storsec_b
OKAY [  0.329s]
Finished. Total time: 1.052s
Rebooting into bootloader                          OKAY [  0.032s]
Finished. Total time: 0.133s
Sending 'radio_b' (73340 KB)                       OKAY [  3.129s]
Writing 'radio_b'                                  (bootloader) Flashing Pack version SSD:g670-00067-200702-B-6648702
(bootloader) Flashing partition modem_b
OKAY [  0.492s]
Finished. Total time: 5.906s
Rebooting into bootloader                          OKAY [  0.041s]
Finished. Total time: 0.292s
--------------------------------------------
Bootloader Version...: b4s4-0.3-6622442
Baseband Version.....: g670-00067-200702-B-6648702
Serial Number........: 9APAY1EN2K
--------------------------------------------
extracting android-info.txt (0 MB) to RAM...
Checking 'product'                                 OKAY [  0.057s]
Checking 'version-bootloader'                      OKAY [  0.058s]
Checking 'version-baseband'                        OKAY [  0.057s]
Setting current slot to 'b'                        OKAY [  0.598s]
extracting boot.img (64 MB) to disk... took 1.493s
archive does not contain 'boot.sig'
Sending 'boot_b' (65536 KB)                        OKAY [  2.800s]
Writing 'boot_b'                                   OKAY [  0.343s]
extracting dtbo.img (8 MB) to disk... took 0.135s
archive does not contain 'dtbo.sig'
Sending 'dtbo_b' (8192 KB)                         OKAY [  0.440s]
Writing 'dtbo_b'                                   OKAY [  0.122s]
archive does not contain 'dt.img'
archive does not contain 'recovery.img'
extracting vbmeta.img (0 MB) to disk... took 0.000s
archive does not contain 'vbmeta.sig'
Sending 'vbmeta_b' (4 KB)                          OKAY [  0.120s]
Writing 'vbmeta_b'                                 OKAY [  0.073s]
archive does not contain 'vbmeta_system.img'
extracting super_empty.img (0 MB) to disk... took 0.000s
Rebooting into fastboot                            OKAY [  0.060s]
< waiting for any device >
Sending 'system_b' (4 KB)                          OKAY [  0.001s]
Updating super partition                           OKAY [  0.009s]
Resizing 'product_b'                               OKAY [  0.006s]
Resizing 'system_b'                                OKAY [  0.005s]
Resizing 'vendor_b'                                OKAY [  0.006s]
archive does not contain 'boot_other.img'
archive does not contain 'odm.img'
extracting product.img (1691 MB) to disk... took 76.264s
archive does not contain 'product.sig'
Resizing 'product_b'                               OKAY [  0.006s]
Sending sparse 'product_b' 1/7 (262140 KB)         OKAY [ 11.117s]
Writing 'product_b'                                OKAY [  2.426s]
Sending sparse 'product_b' 2/7 (262140 KB)         OKAY [ 11.277s]
Writing 'product_b'                                OKAY [  1.429s]
Sending sparse 'product_b' 3/7 (262140 KB)         OKAY [ 15.422s]
Writing 'product_b'                                OKAY [  1.433s]
Sending sparse 'product_b' 4/7 (262140 KB)         OKAY [ 11.898s]
Writing 'product_b'                                OKAY [  1.408s]
Sending sparse 'product_b' 5/7 (262140 KB)         OKAY [ 12.144s]
Writing 'product_b'                                OKAY [  1.425s]
Sending sparse 'product_b' 6/7 (262140 KB)         OKAY [ 12.674s]
Writing 'product_b'                                OKAY [  1.432s]
Sending sparse 'product_b' 7/7 (158888 KB)         OKAY [  8.753s]
Writing 'product_b'                                OKAY [  0.836s]
archive does not contain 'product_services.img'
extracting system.img (786 MB) to disk... took 43.961s
archive does not contain 'system.sig'
Resizing 'system_b'                                OKAY [  0.005s]
Sending sparse 'system_b' 1/4 (262140 KB)          OKAY [ 13.143s]
Writing 'system_b'                                 OKAY [  2.450s]
Sending sparse 'system_b' 2/4 (262140 KB)          OKAY [ 13.939s]
Writing 'system_b'                                 OKAY [  1.420s]
Sending sparse 'system_b' 3/4 (262140 KB)          OKAY [ 13.836s]
Writing 'system_b'                                 OKAY [  1.440s]
Sending sparse 'system_b' 4/4 (18616 KB)           OKAY [  1.159s]
Writing 'system_b'                                 OKAY [  0.148s]
extracting system_other.img (72 MB) to disk... took 2.324s
archive does not contain 'system.sig'
Sending 'system_a' (74668 KB)                      OKAY [  3.188s]
Writing 'system_a'                                 OKAY [  0.426s]
extracting vendor.img (452 MB) to disk... took 23.394s
archive does not contain 'vendor.sig'
Resizing 'vendor_b'                                OKAY [  0.007s]
Sending sparse 'vendor_b' 1/2 (262140 KB)          OKAY [ 11.845s]
Writing 'vendor_b'                                 OKAY [  2.434s]
Sending sparse 'vendor_b' 2/2 (201044 KB)          OKAY [  9.075s]
Writing 'vendor_b'                                 OKAY [  1.161s]
archive does not contain 'vendor_other.img'
Erasing 'userdata'                                 OKAY [  0.618s]
Erase successful, but not automatically formatting.
File system type raw not supported.
Erasing 'metadata'                                 OKAY [  0.043s]
Erase successful, but not automatically formatting.
File system type raw not supported.
Rebooting                                          OKAY [  0.000s]
Finished. Total time: 340.607s
```

Comment: Have you tried to set manually the active boot partition like `fastboot --set-active=b`? (b because based on your log the stock firmware seem to be installed into slot b, you can also try to set it to `a`)

Comment: I did the first 3 tries without specifying the slot (the installation itself happened in slot B). Then tried Slot=all, but that too did not work. Will try --set-active= b and try again.